# Trigger Select Option (option contains more than one word)

Tags: triggers, click, html-select

This code not working when single option contains more than one word

```js
$(document).on('click', '#mybtn', function(){
 var val = $('#myval').val();
 if($("#mylist").find("option:contains('"+val+"')").length){
  $("select#mylist option[value="+val+"]").prop('selected',true).click();
 }
});
```

[working example](https://jsfiddle.net/Hafid/wnL23fgv/)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not wrapping the values in quotes.

Try:

```
$("select#mylist option[value='"+val+"']").prop('selected',true).click();
```

Note that where you have `value="+value+"`, this has now got two single quotes wrapping the value to make it `value='"+value+"'`.

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/61qbmf2u/)

As a slight aside, I would recommend trying not to use spaces for IDs and option values.

Comment: Thank you very much Martin ! It's working ! Have a nice day !

Comment: The list is generated dynamically from google sheet, I will try to follow your advice, eliminate the spaces of the values, or put something else (rows numbers for example) in the values. Thank you Martin !